# Iterative quantum phase estimation - real device

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I'm trying to implement the iterative quantum phase estimation on a real (IBM) quantum computer. I'm using the code below. When I run this code on a simulator the results are the expected ones, but when running on a real device the results don't follow any pattern.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# QML
from pennylane import numpy as np
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit.tools.monitor import job_monitor

shots=32000

# Key with the maximum probability - maior in Portuguese
def maior(dic):
    m=list(dic)[0]
    for n in list(dic):
        if dic[n]>dic[m]:
            m=n
    return m

from key import tok
from qiskit import IBMQ #2
IBMQ.save_account(tok, overwrite=True)

IBMQ.load_account()
provider =IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q-minho', group='academicprojects', project='quantalab')
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_toronto') #4


# ## Iterative Quantum Phase Estimation Algorithm
def get_circuit_phase(t,
        QC,
        clbits,
        qubits,
        ancilla,
        backend=None,
    ):
        mycircuit=QuantumCircuit(2)
        mycircuit.cx(0,1)
        mycircuit.rx(2*t,0)
        mycircuit.rz(2*t,1)
        mycircuit.cx(0,1)
        mycircuit.cy(0,1)
        mycircuit.ry(2*t,0)
        mycircuit.cy(0,1)
        #print(mycircuit.draw())

        # Circuit -> controlled gate
        CU=mycircuit.to_gate().control(1)

        res = []
        # start with the iteration
        phase = -2 * np.pi
        factor = 0
        iterations = 3

        # generate the qubit list on which the Unitary is applied
        qargs = [ancilla]
        for q in qubits:
            qargs.append(q)

        exponent = 2 ** (iterations - 1)
        for it in range(iterations):
            # start
            QC.reset(ancilla)
            QC.h(ancilla)
            # add the inverse rotation
            inv_phase = phase * factor

            QC.p(inv_phase, ancilla)

            # add the controlled Unitary of iteration it
            
            # need to add exponential amount of matrices
            for _ in range(int(exponent)):
                QC = QC.compose(CU, qubits=qargs)
            exponent /= 2

            # add H gate
            QC.h(ancilla)
            QC.measure(ancilla, clbits[it])

            
            if backend == None:  # simulating
                backend=Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator")


            t_qpe = transpile(QC, backend,optimization_level=3)
            job = backend.run(t_qpe, shots=shots)
            job_monitor(job)
       
            counts = job.result().get_counts(QC)

            #  mai is the key with the most probability.
            mai=maior(counts)

            # Save the bit 
            res.append(int(mai[3-it-1]))

            # if bit measured is 1
            if mai[3-it-1] == "1":
                factor += 1 / 2  # add the phase factor

            factor = factor / 2  # shift each towards one weight right

        # phase has now been stored in the clbits
        # returning its binary representation

        # need to reverse as LSB is stored at the zeroth index and
        # not the last
        res = res[::-1]

        # find decimal phase
        dec = 0
        weight = 1 / 2
        for k in res:
            dec += (weight) * k
            weight /= 2

        return dec


for estado in [-1,1]:
    tau=[]
    phase=[]
    for t in range(0,30,1):
        nq = 3    # number of qubits
        m = 3    # number of classical bits
        q = QuantumRegister(nq,'q')
        c = ClassicalRegister(m,'c')
        qc = QuantumCircuit(q,c)
        qc.h(0)
        qc.initialize(params=[0, 1/np.sqrt(2),estado*1/np.sqrt(2), 0],qubits=[1,2])
        t=t/5
        tau.append(t)
        x=get_circuit_phase(t,
        QC=qc,
        clbits=[0,1,2],
        qubits=[1,2],
        ancilla=[0], backend=backend
    )   
        phase.append(x)
    if estado==-1:
        plt.plot(tau,phase,label="- state")   
    if estado==1:
        plt.plot(tau,phase,label="+ state")
plt.xlabel("$tau$")
plt.ylabel("$theta$")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I hope anyone can help with this issue, my sincere thanks,

Gabriela Oliveira.

Comment: Please note that not all features available on the simulator can be used on real QPU. For example conditioning on classical register which is employed in middle-of-circuit measurement is one of such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic circuit capabilities (eg., circuits with control flow) are not yet supported by production IBM hardware. These capabilities will be coming later in 2022 to select devices as per the IBM Quantum Roadmap. For now, you must use a simulator.

Comment: Thank you! Not even controlled rotations CX, CY and CZ run on real devices?